# Django 403 Forbidden cuando trato de acceder a /static

Tags: python, django, nginx, digitalocean, static

Estoy haciendo deploy de una app de **Django** en una droplet de **DigitalOcean**, soy nuevo haciendo esto, pero con
 [este tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-django-con-postgres-nginx-y-gunicorn-en-ubuntu-18-04-es) lo logre fácilmente. En primera instancia todo iba bien, pero implementé un widget con **vue.js** y **axios**, y en mi pc sirve muy bien, pero cuando lo subo al servidor me tira **403 forbiden**. 
En mí témplate principal incluyo los archivos que quiero que cargue, pero el único que carga bien es la hoja de estilos.

```
    {% load static %}
    <link href="/static/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Vue2-3.js -->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/Vue/vue.global.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/Vue/vue.js"></script>
    <!-- Axios -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/node_modules/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/agro

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name agr.xyz www.agr.xyz 111.222.333.444;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/killua/agroiot;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Incluso los iconos guardados en /static que antes funcionaba, lo dejaron de hacer.

```
<img src="{% static 'icons/logo_azul_degrae.svg' %}"  width="30" height="30" fill="red">
```

Parte de mi settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['dominio1','dominio2','ipserver']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Creo que una opción seria usar los CDN de esas librerías, pero me gustaría que funcionara con los scripts que tengo en static. Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

también soy nueva con Django pero tengo entendido que servir archivos estáticos en desarrollo es diferente a servirlos en producción según lo dice la misma documentación de Django:

Durante el desarrollo, si usa django.contrib.staticfiles, esto se hará automáticamente cuando DEBUG se establezca en True (Esto le indica a Django que esta en modo Desarrollo, si DEBUG esta en Falso significa que esta en producción)

Este método es extremadamente ineficaz y probablemente inseguro , por lo que no es adecuado para la producción .

Consulte Implementación de archivos estáticos para conocer las estrategias adecuadas para entregar archivos estáticos en entornos de producción.  Te comparto este link donde explica estrategias para servir archivos en producción.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Espero te sirva.